# Contrastive loss problem in a character-level, siamese NN model

Tags: keras, nlp, loss-function

**Summary: my NN with contrastive loss does not work, need help debugging**

Background:
I am trying to replicate [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W16-1617)

At first, I used binary crossentropy for loss, and the results were very good, but there was a caveat. The model correctly predicted which job titles were similar, but only if it had seen both titles in the training data. If it saw a given title for the first time, it would ALWAYS predict 1 (i.e. that they are similar). This is very undesirable for me product-wise.

Then, I tried the following implementation of the contrastive loss:

```
def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """Contrastive loss from Hadsell-et-al.'06
    http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf
    """
    margin = 1
    sqaure_pred = K.square(y_pred)
    margin_square = K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0))
    return K.mean(y_true * sqaure_pred + (1 - y_true) * margin_square)
```

However, what happens now is that the model always predicts all zeros.
I run this code with print_tensor...

```
    sqaure_pred =  K.print_tensor(K.square(y_pred))
    margin_square =  K.print_tensor(K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))
    return  K.print_tensor(K.mean(y_true * sqaure_pred + (1 - y_true) * margin_square))
```

...and this is what I saw
[image: training_contrastive_loss]

Any ideas what I should try next?

This is the model:

```
def build_blstm_encoder(params):
    lstm = params['lstm']
    nb_tokens = params['nb_tokens']
    maxlen = params['max_seq_len']
    offer_rep_dim = params['offer_rep_dim']
    emb_len = params['emb_len']

    input_1 = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')
    input_2 = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')
    emb_layer = Embedding(nb_tokens, output_dim=emb_len, input_length=maxlen, mask_zero=False)
    blstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(output_dim=lstm, return_sequences=True), merge_mode='concat', weights=None)
    dense = Dense(offer_rep_dim, activation='relu')

    blstm_encoders = []
    for char_array in [input_1, input_2]:
        embs = emb_layer(char_array)
        blstm = blstm_layer(embs)
        dropout = Dropout(0.15)(blstm)
        dense_ = dense(dropout)
        flatten = Flatten()(dense_)
        blstm_encoders.append(flatten)

    distance = Dot([1, 1], normalize=True)(blstm_encoders)
    return Model([input_1, input_2], [distance])
```

The optimizer is just Adam() (default parameters)

**Questions:**
Any idea what went wrong?
What would you try next?